# MonoGame Project Templates: "Windows 10 UAP" vs "Windows 10 Universal Project"?

Tags: monogame

I want to create a new monogame project for Windows 10 development. When I go to create the project, I see that there are two Windows 10 Project Templates: "Windows 10 UAP Project" and "Windows 10 Universal Project".

[image]

Is one better than the other? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: https://www.rizamarhaban.com/2015/08/29/monogame-uap-uwp-for-windows-10-build-10240/

Universal Project seems to be also compatabile with Windows Phone

Comment: I created the "Universal Project" successfully in VS2015. I tried to create the "UAP Project" and it tells me that I need VS2010.